# Unable to locate persister

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, exception

I have the following problem when i try to do the findCliente method. I have the class Cliente in the package model and when i run the findCliente controller I get this exception here. I don't know where I'm wrong because I don't have much skill with JPA and Spring Suite. Can someone tell me how to fix this exception?

Exception

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: it.myshop.orm.model.Cliente
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: it.myshop.orm.model.Cliente
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3416)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3357)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.find(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.find(Unknown Source)
    it.myshop.orm.impl.ClienteServiceImpl.getById(ClienteServiceImpl.java:23)
    it.myshop.orm.controller.ClienteController.findCliente(ClienteController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

org.hibernate.UnknownEntityTypeException: Unable to locate persister: it.myshop.orm.model.Cliente
    org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.locateEntityPersister(MetamodelImpl.java:727)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.locateEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:3019)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1800(SessionImpl.java:201)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2715)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:2698)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.byId(SessionImpl.java:1180)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3380)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3357)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.find(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.find(Unknown Source)
    it.myshop.orm.impl.ClienteServiceImpl.getById(ClienteServiceImpl.java:23)
    it.myshop.orm.controller.ClienteController.findCliente(ClienteController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

AppConfig

```
package it.myshop.orm.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfig;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver;

import it.myshop.orm.dao.ClienteService;
import it.myshop.orm.impl.ClienteServiceImpl;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("it.myshop.orm.controller")
public class AppConfig {
    
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        
        InternalResourceViewResolver iwv = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        iwv.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        iwv.setSuffix(".jsp");
        iwv.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        
        return iwv;
    }


//BEAN CONNESSIONE AL DB
@Bean
public DataSource getDbConnection() {
    
    DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/corso-spring-ud?serverTimezone=CET");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    
    return ds;
}


@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManager() {

HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
adapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
adapter.setGenerateDdl(true); 

LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
factory.setDataSource(getDbConnection());
factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter); //passo adapter
factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName()); 

return factory;

}


@Bean
public ClienteService getClienteServiceImpl() {
    return new ClienteServiceImpl();
}
```

App Initializer

```
package it.myshop.orm.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import it.myshop.orm.config.AppConfig;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Class<?>[] {AppConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }

}
```

ClienteController

```
package it.myshop.orm.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import it.myshop.orm.dao.ClienteService;
import it.myshop.orm.impl.ClienteServiceImpl;
import it.myshop.orm.model.Cliente;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/cliente")
public class ClienteController {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private ClienteService cs;

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add() {
        
//      cs.add(null);
        System.out.println("Sei nella pagina di aggiunta");
        
        return null;
    }
    
    
    
    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/findCliente")
    public String findCliente() {
        
        Cliente c = cs.getById(1);
        System.out.println("Sei nella pagina di find del Cliente");
        
        return c.getNome() + " " + c.getCognome();
    }
```

Cliente

```
package it.myshop.orm.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column
    private String nome;
    @Column
    private String cognome;
    @Column
    private String codiceFiscale;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String telefono;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }
    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }
    public String getCodiceFiscale() {
        return codiceFiscale;
    }
    public void setCodiceFiscale(String codiceFiscale) {
        this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }
    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Interface ClienteService

```
package it.myshop.orm.dao;

import it.myshop.orm.model.Cliente;

public interface ClienteService {

    public Cliente add(Cliente c);
    
    public Cliente getById(int id);
}
```

ClienteServiceImpl

```
package it.myshop.orm.impl;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import it.myshop.orm.dao.ClienteService;
import it.myshop.orm.model.Cliente;

public class ClienteServiceImpl implements ClienteService {

    
    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;
    
    @Override
    public Cliente add(Cliente c) {
        em.persist(c);
        return c;
    }

    @Override
    public Cliente getById(int id) {
        return em.find(Cliente.class, id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve this problem you have two options. You can choose either of which .
1- you must have all you entity classes declared in you hibernate configuration file.
for this you must add you entity classes specially "Cliente" in hibernate.cfg.xml file
like this :

`<mapping class="entity.Client"/>`

or

2-another way is adding this entity to session configuration like this :

`SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml") .addAnnotatedClass(Cliente.class) .buildSessionFactory();`

Comment: Thank you, I solved the error with the second option!

Comment: why factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());  does not work?